# como puedo navegar a otra ruta usando parametros opcionales en la url

Tags: angular, rutas

tengo un problema. Tengo un filtro que de busqueda y paso esos parametros de busqueda a otra vista a traves de los parametros en la ruta. el problema que tenga actualmente es que el filtro tiene 6 parametros, y puede que el usuario solo llene 4 de los 6 campos del formulario, y cuando lo envia me da error porque en la ruta tengo definido los 6 parametros de esta forma:

```js
{ path: 'inmuebles/:tipo/:transaccion/:pais/:cuartos/:precio_min/:precio_max',component: VistaInmuebleComponent}
```

y asi es como hago el envio del formulario en el boton:

```html
(click)="filtro(formulario.value)" [routerLink]="['/inmuebles',formulario.controls['tipo'].value,formulario.controls['transaccion'].value,formulario.controls['pais'].value,formulario.controls['cuartos'].value,formulario.controls['precio_min'].value,formulario.controls['precio_max'].value]"
```

Existe alguna forma de poner los parametros "precio_min" y "precio_max" como opcional ? que si el usuario no los completa igual se pueda enviar el formulario ? en este momento me da error porque en la ruta tengo definidos 6 parametros y envio 4 si el usuario no selecciona esos 2. Como podria hacer para resolver eso? gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 4):

La documentación oficial de angular explica que se debe utilizar `route parameters` cuando se tienen parámetros no opcionales ([documentación](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-required-or-optional)), cuando se trabaja con parámetros opcionales se recomienda utilizar `query parameters`. Para este caso en particular se podría implementar de la siguiente manera:

```
{ path: 'inmuebles/:tipo/:transaccion/:pais/:cuartos', component: VistaInmuebleComponent }
```

enlace a ruta:

```html
<a (click)="filtro(formulario.value)"
   [routerLink]="['/inmuebles', formulario.controls['tipo'].value, formulario.controls['transaccion'].value, formulario.controls['pais'].value, formulario.controls['cuartos'].value]"
   [queryParams]="{'precio_min': formulario.controls['precio_min'].value, 'precio_max': formulario.controls['precio_max'].value}">
  ...
</a>
```

recepción de parámetros:

```js
// ...
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({ ... })
export class VistaInmuebleComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params); // {"precio_min": <min>, "precio_max": <max>}
      });
  }
}
```

Para más información sobre `query parameters` puedes revisar este [enlace](https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/).

Comment: Hola @Jonathan, gracias por responder. coloque tal cual como lo hiciste pero me da error. cuando defino la ruta, aqui: { path: 'inmuebles/:tipo/:transaccion/:pais/:cuartos', component: VistaInmuebleComponent } no deberian de ir los 6 parametros? coloque eso tal cual y el otro codigo que colocaste con el queryParams pero me muestra error, parte del error dice esto: compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected ] at the end of the expression [['/inmuebles',formulario.controls['tipo'].value,formulario.controls['transaccion'].value,...

Comment: Hola, @JulianProg, primero que nada, como había explicado en la respuesta, no se pueden poner parámetros de ruta opcionales, es decir, los parámetros: `tipo`, `transaccion`, `pais` y `cuartos` son parámetros fijos que no pueden faltar, los parámetros opcionales `precio_min` y `precio_max` se pasan mediante `query params`, un ejemplo de la ruta formada sería `/inmuebles/<tipo>/<transaccion>/<pais>/<cuartos>?precio_min=<min>&precio_max=<max>`.
El error que mencionas es porque pusiste un corchete de más al inicio `[['/inmue...` -> `['/inmue...`

Comment: Ok, ya logre resolver amigo. Ahora... se que no es lo ideal, pero que podria usar para que al recargar una pagina o vista los datos que tenia no se pierdan y se vuelvan a mostrar? seria con local storage o habria una mejor forma de hacerlo?